# I get a 403 when I go to http://localhost/~admin/

Tags: apache-http-server, php, osx-mountain-lion

I'm running mac osx 10.8.

when I go to localhost or 127.0.0.1/ my browser says: "It Works!".

However when I go to localhost/~admin/ or 127.0.0.1/~admin/ my browser says:

"Forbidden

You don't have permission to access /~admin/ on this server."

***How do I change this?!??!?! It's driving me nuts!***

**This is my /etc/apache2/users/admin.conf:**

```
<Directory "/Users/admin/Sites/">
        Options Indexes MultiViews
        AllowOverride All
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
</Directory>
```

**I created aliases in my .bash_profile file so that I can start, restart and stop Apache quickly:**

```
alias startApache="sudo apachectl start"
alias stopApache="sudo apachectl stop"
alias restartApache="sudo apachectl restart"
```

**In my /etc/apache2/httpd.conf file I turned on php5:**

```
LoadModule php5_module        libexec/apache2/libphp5.so
```

**I also made sure to change the permissions for my admin.conf file with this command in terminal:**

```
sudo chmod 644 username.conf
```

Comment: Is your username actually admin? Does `~/Sites/` exist?

Comment: yeah my username is admin lol 

I typed ~/Sites/ in terminal and it gave me this so it exists I think:
-bash: /Users/admin/Sites/: is a directory

Comment: @ekaj I tried that and it didn't work

Comment: @ekaj I also made sure to restart apache after doing chmod 755

Comment: Hey guys help!!! It's still not working :(

Comment: What does your /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default look like?

Comment: new-host:users admin$ cd /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default
-bash: cd: /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default: No such file or directory